# Black border for video poster

Tags: css

How to add the black border to video poster? I tried to figure it out but it not worked for me.
Thanks for your help...

```
echo '<video id="video" width="300px" height="200px" controls poster="'.$image.'" style="padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ddd; border-radius: 4px;"><source src="'.$video.'" preload="metadata"></video>';

<style>
video[poster]{
border:1px solid #000000;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can’t apply a border to the poster only. But you can apply a border to the video element which includes the poster.

```css
video {
  border: 5px solid crimson; border-radius: 10px;  
}
```

```html
<video controls poster="http://picsum.photos/320/180">
  <source src="https://donald.au/bugs/so-77672744.mp4" preload="metadata">
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have video with border but a poster without a border looks naked :)) by the way - maybe you know a html/js player for avi &divx?